# Using becomeFirstResponder causes cancel button to not work

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, becomefirstresponder

I have a `UISearchDisplayController` (searchDisplayCtr) and a `UISearchBar` (searchBar). I am trying to give focus to the search bar and bring up the keyboard when I click the search icon in the alphabet scroll on the right. If I include,

```
[self.searchDisplayCtr setActive:YES];
[self.searchDisplayCtr.searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
```

It brings up the keyboard and selects the search bar but the cancel button does not work consistently. I have tried resigning first responder, setting active to NO and both in `searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch`, but it doesn't help. The cancel button will work only if no other letters on the alphabet scroll have been clicked yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is apparently necessary to scroll up to the top of the table before setting first responder. The code ended up being

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
[self.searchBar  becomeFirstResponder];
```