# UISearchBar Cancel button is visible but doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have the same problem as [Using becomeFirstResponder causes cancel button to not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007059/using-becomefirstresponder-causes-cancel-button-to-not-work), except that the solution doesn't work in my case.

I created a storyboard project with a Navigation controller and a Table view controller in it.  I added a UISearchDisplayController to the table view and all works well until I try to access the searchDisplayController as seen below in the code snippet.  I am using a section index and added UITableViewIndexSearch (or @"{search}") to the top of the section titles so that the magnifying glass shows at the beginning of the A - Z index.  When I click on the section index the following function is called:

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
  if ([title isEqualToString:UITableViewIndexSearch])
  {
    [self.searchDisplayController setActive:TRUE animated:TRUE];   // Either of these two lines
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar becomeFirstResponder]; // will cause the search bar cancel button to not work
    return 0;
  }
  return index - 1;
}
```

If I comment out **both** of the lines that access searchDisplayController then the search bar cancel button works as expected. If either of the two lines is **not** commented out in the code then the cancel button on the search bar acts as if it were not even there.  Removing the `becomeFirstResponder` line means that I must click/touch in the search bar field to transfer focus to it, so in this case when I click on the cancel button the search bar gets focus.  It's as if the cancel button is seen transparently through the search bar but can't be clicked/touched.  Take those two lines of code out and the cancel button works again.

What the heck is going on?